# What is the example of a continuous function which is not an indefinite integral?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

By Royden's Real Analysis (3rd), chap 5. Thm 14, it reads that

'A function F is an indefinite integral if and only if it is absolutely continuous. '

What is the continuous but absolutely-DISconinuous function which is not an indefinite integral of any other function?

Comment: I can imagine the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) will fit. But there is probably much simpler examples.

Comment: Cantor staircase function.

Comment: Probably it's clearer to write "not absolutely continuous," rather than "absolutely discontinuous," which sounds badly pathological.